# How to provide password to MSBUILD runtime and use that in Powershell script

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, msbuildcommunitytasks

I want MSBUILD show a POPup to enter password during/before execution of build definition.I want to pass this password to powershell script I will be running as part of MSBuild definition.
I already implemented a scenario where password is encrypted in a file checked-in on TFS and is read by powershell(MSBUILD) while executing a  build definition.But for security purposes I want password to be entered by a build definition invoker during runtime .

Can we achieve this ?

I am using TFS 2013,MSBUILD  12.0 and VS 2013 for this purpose.And can use only these tools and nothing else.

Comment: I am Using TFS ,MSBUILD and VS 2013 for build deployment.I can not use other opensource tool Like jenkins.

Comment: You cannot get any "prompt" in the build process neither in xaml or powershell.  The build server is running as a service.  But like Martin suggested below, you can modify you xaml or pass a parameter to your pre-build script to pass in the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the xaml file to take a password as part of queuing the build from VS or Web Access.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx

You can add a custom property and pass it in...